# 0-byte partition and storage being inaccessible on a Mediatek device

Tags: partitions, device-firmware, mediatek

I have an Infinix Note 10 Pro. I would like to know if there is any way to fix the 0-byte partitions issue and storage being inaccessible. I saw this when I was trying to copy out the `vbmeta` and `boot.bin` files for rooting, and for some reason, I got that issue. Prior to the issue, I upgraded my firmware after a full wipe, and that's when the issue popped. It is also to note that I do not have access to my internal memory for some reason either.

I am absolutely clueless about how these Mediatek devices work. I need advice since I have skimmed through multiple forums, and am unable to land on a decisive conclusion. In short, I do not want to ruin more than I already have. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all good, resolved by flashing the whole stock rom again. weird stuff.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).